# How to read and write txt file in android 10 and above? also after uninstall and reinstall the app i want read previous app created txt file

Tags: android, kotlin

I can create a text file on Android 10 and above, but when I uninstall and reinstall the app, I cannot read the previously created text file. My question is: How can I read a file inside a specific location in the file manager on Android 10 and above?

Comment: `but when I uninstall and reinstall the app, I cannot read the previously created text file` - are you saving the file to the external storage, or the internal storage? If the former, then can you tell more about why you're not able to locate that file? It's not supposed to be removed when you uninstall the app.

Comment: Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`, and let the user decide what content your app should access.

Comment: i store that text file in public directory inside document folder and also i don't want to use file picker like concept.

Comment: Egor it's throw error when i try to access that file like this 'File content Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/base_url.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)' but i check the file it's present there,also i tried all method like Uri everythink.